# Can Lua script take variables from sites-available/sites-enabled configs?

Tags: nginx, cookies, lua

I want to parse a cookie to get a username so I have a lua script for that. Can the script use variable where I store cookie from sites-available/sites-enabled configs? Is it correct in general?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can set/get cookies

```
local cookieName = "cookie_1"
local varName = "cookie_" .. cookieName
local cookieValue = ngx.var[varName]
```

The detailed docs and APIs with examples are good place to start [link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_cookie)